# nuxt.js unable to refer store value?

Tags: session, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using `nuxt.js` to implement a online commerce.

I am doing something like the below to check user is logged in or not.

- In my header, would like to determine display some part(like point, mypage button ... etc) or not by a value of `isSigned`, which is boolean type variable. In my case, I use `computed` function in a template.
- In my vuex store, would like to update session(action-mutation) in `nuxtServerInit` so I could reassign values from the API server.

Here is a part of header code, it is `computed` to check `isSign`.

```
computed : {
    isSign : function () {
        console.log('HEADER COMPUTED EXECUTED ISSIGNED', this.$store.state.session, new Date().getTime());
        return this.$store.state.session.signed;
    }
}
```

Ans here is corresponding store code, in mutation.

```
export const mutations = {
  sessionUpdateSeccess : function (state, payload) {
    console.log('SESSION UPDATE SECCESS :: ', state, payload)
    state.signed = payload.signed;
    console.log('SESSION UPDATE SECCESS END :: ', state, payload, new Date().getTime())
  }
}
```

The mutations code works fine, but in header component, `signed` value is still `true`, even though state has changed.

So I print the end time of each process.

- `mutations` : 1540520171177
- `computed` : 1540520170690

Until far, I reached a conclusion that I should not refer `store` value in `computed`.

I would like to know common way to check user session in nuxt. Thanks.

Comment: don't assign value at store state declaration, so it will work fine

Comment: can u create a reproducion on https://template.nuxtjs.org ?

Comment: @Aldarund Thanks. I will add a comment after I try that site, it would be about this weekend.